# Kickstart Fedora server iso using usb

Tags: redhat, installation, fedora, kickstart

Hi I need to create a Fedora Server image with my application in it using kickstart installation.
I have executed following steps :

1. Downloaded the fedora35 Image from https://getfedora.org/en/server/download/  (Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-35-1.2)
2. mount the iso :   mount -t iso9660 -o loop Fedora-Server-dvd-x86_64-35-1.2.iso /mnt/
3. mkdir /var/iso
4. cp -a /mnt/ /var/iso
5. cd /var/iso/
6. vim ks.cfg (contents of the ks file are below) : this file is auto generated while manual fedora install.

```
# Generated by Anaconda 35.22.2
# Generated by pykickstart v3.34
#version=DEVEL
# Use graphical install
graphical

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=ens160 --ipv6=auto --no-activate

# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom

%packages
@^server-product-environment
%end

# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable


# Generated using Blivet version 3.3.0
ignoredisk --only-use=sda
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append="reboot=pci i915.force_probe=4571 module_blacklist=pinctrl_elkhartlake" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

# Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=94208
part /mnt/deviceBoot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=95367
part /var/device/log --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda --size=858306

# Use auto partitioning...
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
#autopart

# System timezone
timezone Europe/Amsterdam --utc

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $y$j9T$LueSmDWWdRgLiywynK3Edq1p$6j11FHKiANZhvvDoJG9wcnhgaJ75oKeieZ.rj7sz8
```

7. vim isolinux/isolinux.cfg
   Added the label kickstart and made that default:

default kickstart

label kickstart
menu label ^Testing for device
kernel vmlinuz
append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=deviceimage inst.ks=hd:LABEL=deviceimage quiet

8. genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "deviceimage" -volset "deviceimage" -A "deviceimage" 
   -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table 
   -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o newfedora.iso  ../mountedIso/
   (the above command is executed in single line)
9. scp the fedoraimage from the machine to widnows and using rufus 3.17 making a bootable usb
10. using this usb on device.

Problems statements  :

1. When running on the virtual machine it installs properly but when trying on hardware it gives error on
   Installation source and Installation Destination.
2. When I remove the parttion info from the ks.cfg and enable autopart then Installation destination does not
   appear but Installation source remains same.

Please guide me for the abouve issues.

Comment: What's the actual error that it gives you?\

Comment: Not able to select the installation source(Error setting up base repository)

Comment: Your commands specify `cp -a /mnt /var/iso` - did you forget the `-r`?

Comment: No, I used that too.